# Scaffold ASP.NET Core with Full Framework and Unit Test Projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, xunit.net, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to find a way to scaffold a new ASP.NET Core site that runs on the full .NET Framework (net461) and contains a unit test project. Is this doable? All of the options for `dotnet new mvc` don't seem to allow `net461` as a framework. The same is true for the `xunit` project type.

Answer (score 2):

Build your own template which contains two projects. It's extremely easy. Create and setup several projects in Visual Studio and put `.template.config\template.json` file to the root solution level:

[image]

`template.json` contents:

```
{
    "classifications": [ "Web" ],
    "name": "ASP.NET Core project AND xUnit project both targeting .NET 461",
    "identity": "fweb", // Unique name for this template
    "shortName": "fweb", // Short name that can be used on the cli
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#" // Specify that this template is in C#.
    },
    "sourceName": "FullWebApp",
    "preferNameDirectory": "true"
}
```

Then run `dotnet new --install` with solution path as a parameter:

```
dotnet new --install "D:\YourFullPath\DotNetTemplates"
```

Template `fweb` has been created! Go to target folder and try to create new projects from template:

```
dotnet new fweb
```

It's done. Read more about template packaging (NuGet) and name parametrization here:

[How To Create A dotnet new Project Template In .NET Core](http://pioneercode.com/post/how-to-create-a-dot-net-new-project-template-in-dot-net-core#create)

[How to create your own templates for dotnet new](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/02/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/)

Comment: I have a sample of a console project and unit test project at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-template-samples/tree/master/05-multi-project